# Teradata odbc driver for Mac OS sierra

Tags: odbc, teradata, tableau-api, macos-sierra

I am trying to connect to `Teradata` on my Tableau Desktop 9.2.7.

I am on Mac OS Sierra. It shows the following error when I try to connect to `Teradata` database

Detailed Error Message:

```
[iODBC][Driver Manager]dlopen(/Library/Application Support/teradata/client/ODBC/lib/tdata.dylib, 6): Library not loaded: libtdparse.dylib Referenced from: /Library/Application Support/teradata/client/ODBC/lib/tdata.dylib Reason: image not found [iODBC][Driver Manager]Specified driver could not be loaded Unable to connect to the server "wm1". Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.
```

I have already installed the required ODBC drivers from the `Teradata` website. I even tried installing the previous versions of the driver. I'm not able to get past this error message. Can someone guide me towards a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I’d the same problem and am on Sierra too. but it was resolved after i installed the Teradata ODBC driver v16.20 (previously was v15.00). See if it works?